# SQLCMDMODE from SSMS. Can I set -b mode when using :r to include files?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sqlcmd

As far as I read [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) there is no variable that corresponds to the -b flag of the command (on error batch abort).
I found no to enable this mode inside a script when running in sqlcmd mode.
Is there any to force
:r filename
to run in this mode, when called from SSMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't.

Not in the supported subset of options: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx